# monodevelop error: libgluezilla not found

Tags: mono, monodevelop

## ubuntu19.04 disco, monodevelop 7.8.4(build 2)

Using monodevelop, I created a new solution(form based gtk# gui application). I added a Windows.Forms.Webbrowser control to my Form1.

When I start debugging, the application quit without showing a form at all. Instead of it, monodevelop left these messages below : 
libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed

But libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil is already installed in the os ( as below ).

```
$ sudo apt-cache search libgluezilla
 libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil - Mono Web Browser library (for CLI 4.0)

$ sudo apt-get install libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil
libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil is already latest version (6.0.0.313-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1) 
upgraded: 0 , installed: 0, removed: 0, pending: 39.

$ dpkg --contents libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil_6.0.0.313-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1_all.deb
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/4.5/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/gac/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebBrowser/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebBrowser/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/
 -rw-r--r-- root/root    166912 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebBrowser/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebBrowser.dll
 -rw-r--r-- root/root        87 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebBrowser/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebBrowser.dll.config
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/share/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/share/doc/
 drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/share/doc/libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil/
 -rw-r--r-- root/root     14745 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/share/doc/libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil/changelog.Debian.gz
 -rw-r--r-- root/root     33084 2019-07-14 17:56 ./usr/share/doc/libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil/copyright
 lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2019-07-14 18:12 ./usr/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.WebBrowser.dll -> ../gac/Mono.WebBrowser/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebBrowser.dll
```

In the .pkg, there is a Mono.WebBrowser.dll but there seems to be no libgluezilla* at all. Is the ubuntu pkg correct?

What is the problem and how to fix it? Why monodevelop complains and doesn't run the applications using Windows.Forms.Webbrowser control at all?

Comment: How did you installed MonoDevelop? Do you use PPA or third-party repository? I do not see its package in [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=monodevelop)

Comment: I installed : 7.8.4.1-0xamarin6+ubuntu1804b1.

Comment: I download from monodevelop official site for latest ubuntu and installed  it. : 7.8.4.1-0xamarin6+ubuntu1804b1.  It is for bionic(18.04) but currently no official packages for disco. Is it the cause of this issue?

Comment: I reinstalled mono-complete package for disco. When I executed 'sudo apt-get install mono-complete' from my console, the package name 'libgluezilla' is shown as a 'recommended package'. But there seems to be NO 'libgluezilla' package in ubuntu packages at all(for all suite). Why?